# Plot a perfect looking circle using two functions, always look like an ellipse

Tags: plotting

I want to use the the following two functions to plot a perfect looking circle, but the graph always ends up looking a bit squashed. I've been playing with some of the parameters of the function but can't seem to get it to look right still.

Here is the function:

```
Plot[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't find a question which I think this one duplicates, but this question is addressed in the docs under Plot > Examples > Options > AspectRatio. So suggest closing as "easily found in the documentation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) to `{-1, 1}` and set [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) to `1`.

```
Plot[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Result:

[image]

**PS:** That's one of the way, to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `AspectRatio -> Automatic` (the default value is `1/GoldenRatio`):

```
Plot[{Sqrt[1 - x^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: That is interesting! Why do you think it is set up like that with the default being 1/GoldenRatio? Does it benefit some other type of graphics like that?

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UfPqY.png)'s why ([Ref](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/compare-mathematica/files/MathematicaMaplePlottingAutomation.pdf))

Comment: @TimHUK: I think the idea is that the axes in `Plot` often show different quantities (e.g. meters versus seconds), where `PlotRange->Automatic` would make no sense, and often give extremely stretched results. So WRI chose a fixed ratio that's supposed to be pretty. (But that's really just guessing.)